# Binding DualShock 4 button to AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, remote-control

I setup a dualshock 4 (PS4) controller to work with my Mac Mini for XBMC, which can play games on emulators like SNES9x. The issue I'm having though, is that when I want to quit the game/emulator that I'm playing, it requires a mouse and a keyboard. So what I would like to do ideally, is take an applescript that I have, which terminates the current emulator and bind it to the "PlayStation" button on the controller so when I'm ready, I can quit the current game without having to use a mouse and keyboard. At the same time, it's necessary that every other button on the controller can continue to be mapped normally to buttons in the emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst I don't have a PS4 controller to test this on, you should be able to use [**Keyboard Maestro**](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/)'s Device Key action to run AppleScript or any other action.

[image]

Comment: This looks exactly like the kind of thing that I needed. Thank you very much!

Comment: Alright, after attempting to use this, I'm still running into some issues. What I'm seeing now is that the emulator (SNES9x) launches correctly, and the controller works with it. However, as long as a game is running, it's like the emulator has full control over the BT Controller. When I press the PS button, nothing happens. However, as soon as I press `esc` on the keyboard the PS button works with the Keyboard Maestro macro and closes the emulator out just fine. Any way around this issue?

Comment: @Ryan That seems like an emulator issue, that it's taking unilateral control of the input device. I don't know how you'd get round that though…

Comment: I finally came up with a solution last night, and here's what I did. I went through the conf files for the keyboard, and found what the `esc` key did. I then, assigned that to BT Button 13 (PS Button), then in keyboard maestro, i still assigned the 'quit app' function to SNES9x, but changed it from 'on press' to 'on release'. So now you press the button, an `esc` is immediately fired, then a follow up from keyboard maestro immediately quits the emulator and goes back to XBMC. Thanks for all of your help, George!